# How can I generate and draw random amount of rectangles using a for loop

Tags: c++, random, sfml

I'm trying to implement a sorting visualizer in SFML but can't figure out how to generate a random amount of rectangles, which also have a random height. Is this the right idea?

```
sf::RectangleShape Bars(sf::Vector2f(10, 300));
Bars.setFillColor(sf::Color(173, 216, 230));
Bars.setPosition(100, 0);
std::vector<Bars> bars;
```

Then I would use a for loop to randomly print at different spots?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < bars.size; i++)
 {
      window.draw(Bars);

 }
```

Comment: Firstly you should have found that this doesn't compile. std::vector expects a type in the <> you have provided Bars. Instead create a `std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> bars;`. Then the for-loop would be `{ draw(bars[i]); }`

Comment: After the creation of the vector you can add random Rectangles to it.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thank you so much! how would i create random rects? would i use a for loop that pushes back into the vector?

Comment: That's a reasonable idea.

Comment: I have a question : 'int Amount = 500;

         for (int i=0; i<Amount; i++)
         {
            // seed rand num and create one
            srand(time(0));
            int number = rand() % 100;

            sf::RectangleShape Bar;
            Bar.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, number));
            bars.push_back(Bar);
            window.draw(bars[i]);
         }' // How can i create a  new Bar object every iteration? This code only prints one rect on the screen

Comment: Don't use `rand()` instead use <random> library provided in C++11.

Comment: @Aamir Okay, could you explain to me why it only draws on rect? it should be drawing 500

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random` library provided since C++11 to generate random height.
Another important thing is you need to shift the x-position of each bar to the right so that it doesn't overlap with the previous bar.

The program below generate random bars with random colors.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

constexpr int32_t winWidth {800};
constexpr int32_t winHeight {600};
constexpr int32_t maxBars {50};
constexpr int32_t barWidth {5};
constexpr int32_t maxColors {7};

sf::Color colors[] = {
    sf::Color::White,
    sf::Color::Red,
    sf::Color::Green,
    sf::Color::Blue,
    sf::Color::Yellow,
    sf::Color::Magenta,
    sf::Color::Cyan,
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({winWidth, winHeight}), "Bars");
    window.setFramerateLimit(4);

    // for generating random height
    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine engine(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t> dist(5, winHeight/2);

    // generate all rectangles with their position before draw loop
    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape *> bars;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxBars; ++i) {
        sf::RectangleShape *rect = new sf::RectangleShape;
        // shift each bar to the right
        float xPos = barWidth + (barWidth * i * 2);
        float yPos = (winHeight * .9f);
        rect->setPosition({xPos, yPos});
        bars.push_back(rect);
    }

    while(window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event e;
        while(window.pollEvent(e)) {
            if(e.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if(e.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased) {
                switch(e.key.code) {
                    case sf::Keyboard::Key::Escape:
                        window.close();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // for each bar generate a random height and assign a random color
        for(const auto bar : bars) {
            float height = dist(engine);
            int32_t idx = dist(engine);
            bar->setSize({barWidth, -height});
            bar->setFillColor(colors[ idx % maxColors]);
            window.draw(*bar);
        }
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Although this code is currently too good for my knowledge, i really appreciate the help. I will try and implement it:)

Comment: The basic idea is to assign a unique position to each bar so that they don't overlap and then generate a random height and then draw them.

Comment: I really appreciate the help,  ive never seen "constexpr int32_t" what is this? And std::vector<sf::RectangleShape *> bars; is the asterix a pointer?

Comment: Nothing fancy in the above code, it just uses the modern C++ features. I encourage you to use the modern features like `auto`, `range-based for loop`, `constexpr` etc. Have a look at `http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/21-new-features-of-modern-cpp-to-use-in-your-project/` for a list of some of the features.

Comment: `constexpr` are just like `const` and indicate the value is constant. It was added in C++11.  Unlike `const`, `constexpr` can also be applied to functions. `int32_t` is a fixed width integer declaration. All fixed width types are defined in `<cstdint>` `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer`

Comment: Thank you brother, it might not seem like much but your help comes along way!